# My phone's touchscreen is damaged. Is it possible to control it remotely?

Tags: broken-screen, touchscreen, usb-on-the-go, remote-control

I have an Android 5-based smartphone that I like a lot but it's an old phone and the touchscreen is damaged. The screen works perfectly but there's no user input available. The battery was changed recently and I suppose the technician did a good job fixing the backing side but broke the front part containing the touchscreen.

**Is there an option to access it somehow and make it controllable remotely?** If I use a USB cable, is possible to install TeamViewer or some other remote control software to still use it?

The phone has no other remote control software preinstalled. Its touchscreen broke before I was able to install anything for remote control.

The point is to use its camera and mic functionality, and still use its sensors to do something useful like a remote camera or something similar.

Answer (score 9):

Use an OTG mouse and keyboard.

[From a thread](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/mouse-functionality-in-android-6-or-android-5/27826/2):

> I can confirm that using an USB OTG adapter a wireless Logitech mouse
> and keyboard combo works for me without problem using Fairphone Open
> OS 17.03 (Android 5.1).

Comment: Nice idea, do you know if it works even if you want to attempt in flash rom environment? I was thinking to upgrade also the phone to a new cooked rom android 9 or similar.

Comment: @user3450548 please don't ask off-topic. flashing requires usb connection, you can't use OTG simultaneously

Comment: @alecxs is alway right. However, there is this splitter cable you can use. I cannot confirm if it will work for Android 5, or as the matter in concern, for flashing (because the title says power cable which means it might not be a data cable) https://dl.flipkart.com/s/UaIyHguuuN

Answer (score 5):

If you can manage to get usb debugging working, try [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

> Its features include:
>
> - audio forwarding (Android >= 11)
> - recording
> - mirroring with Android device screen off
> - copy-paste in both directions
> - configurable quality
> - Android device screen as a webcam (V4L2) (Linux-only)
> - physical keyboard/mouse simulation (HID)
> - OTG mode
> - and more…

(from its README)

Comment: Except that you need to interact with the UI to grant the adb permissions in the first place :) so you will have to use otg anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it connected to a computer, you can use [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/). It's a program that lets you view and interact with your device from your desktop. It looks like the minimum Android version required for it is 4.4, so you should be good to go with Android 5.